# Why does SQL Server not respect the .Net isolation level?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have this code:

```
var to = new TransactionOptions();
to.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, to))
{
    someQuery.ToList();
    ts.Complete();
}
```

No matter what, the SQL Server Profiler shows that "someQuery" (and any other query on this transaction) run with an isolation level of "Read Committed".

The only way I can force to run as ReadUncommitted if, before `someQuery.ToList();`, I execute this line:

```
myContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
```

Why does SQL Server not respect the .Net isolation level? What can I do about this?

Comment: Where did `someQuery` come from? If it's not already, do you get a different result if you don't *create* it until you're inside the `TransactionScope`?

Comment: As a side issue, why do you want to use `read uncommitted` vs say `snapshot`?

Comment: It could be the issue with code nesting. Try to create `someQuery` **inside** the block that setups the transaction scope.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Promote your comment to answer, I will accept it!